# How would I compute the frequency of a single value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I compute the frequency(count of occurrence) of the number 5 of this data list?

*Data list: {2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 4, 5, 7, 12, 15, 21, 32, 45, 5, 6, 7, 12}*

**My code:**

```
        int numbers[] = {2,4,6,9,5,4,5,7,12,15,21,32,45,5,6,7,12};
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){

        if(numbers[i]  == 5){
            count = numbers[i];

        }//end of if
    }//end of for
    System.out.println(count);
```

**My output:**

```
 The frequency of 5 is: 5
```

**My desired output:**

```
 The frequency of 5 is 3
```

Comment: Did you search for the solution to this first?

Comment: If you had to do that task manually with a sheet of paper. Would you shout out the result every time you saw a 5? I don't think you'd do that. You'd keep track of how many you saw (either on paper or in your head) and tell us the result *in the end*.

Comment: Maybe you should read again your code... you are printing in a loop and you are printing the number of elements in your list... Maybe use a variable to count elements that are equals to 5 and then print after your loop

Comment: Try to learn "how to search an element into an array/list?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a count variable and increase it everytime when match found. At the end print that variable after for loop as follows:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){

    if(numbers[i]  == 5){
        count++;    
    }//end of if
}//end of for
System.out.println("The frequency of 5 is " + count);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you explain why simply putting count++ prints 3?

Comment: @Jeeven: it seems like you need an explanation of what a loop is (specifically the `for` loop). Unfortunately SO isn't the best place to learn basic principles like that, you should really find a good beginners tutorial and/or book to acquaint yourself with the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following in a *Java 8* manner:

```
int numbers[] = {2,4,6,9,5,4,5,7,12,15,21,32,45,5,6,7,12};
long nbOccurrences = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(i -> i == 5).count();
System.out.println("The number of occurrences of 5 is " + nbOccurrences);
```

Please note that we are not returning **frequency** here but **number of occurrences** of 5. Therefore, the printed message and the code has been adapted.

Comment: You are correct. However, Java is smart enough to use a IntStream given the type of numbers. Try it out in a IDE

Answer (score 0):

Can use `Collections.frequency()`

Just convert your `array` to a `list`.

```java
int[] a = {2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 4, 5, 7, 12, 15, 21, 32, 45, 5, 6, 7, 12};
Integer[] b = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(b), 5));
```